# ayuda con la funcion UNIX_TIMESTAMP en mysql

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Estoy usando la funcion `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` para convertir una fecha a formato unix.

La fecha es esta: `2018-04-16 12:00:00`

cuando uso `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-04-16 12:00:00');`

me devuelve `1524225600` que es igual a `2018-04-16 07:00:00`

¿Por qué pasa eso?

Comment: La puedes convertir también así: `SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ('2018-04-16 12:00:00', '+02:00', @@global.time_zone))) fecha ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque usa el tiempo en utc, depende de tu huso horario.

Agrégale o réstale el tiempo necesario.

Comment: ok gracias, ya le sume el tiempo faltante saludos

Comment: @skycomputer2, si esta respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, por favor **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

UNIX_TIMESTAMP siempre devuelve el tiempo en formato UTC.  Si quieres utilizarla, tu tendrias que hacer la conversion manual de tu tiempo local a UTC.